# Which part of a Javascript statement is literal?

Tags: javascript, variables, literals

I know that fixed values are literals, and variable values are variables. If I have a simple statement such as:

```
var car = "Audi";
```

does it contain a literal? To which part of the statement is the variable applied? Is it "Audi", as that can be changed to another value in another function? Or is it 'car', as the variable name can be changed similarly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "literal" refers to the notation that you use to represent the value that you're assigning to the variable. It does not refer to the value itself, but the way it is written in code.

So in your simple example, the string value `"Audi"` is assigned to the variable `car` by writing the literal word "Audi" in double quotes on the right hand side of the expression. The word "car" in your code is an [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables), rather than a literal, as it *identifies* the variable by its name.

Answer (score 1):

`"Audi"` is a string literal, standing for the string of characters `Audi`; it denotes a [*string primitive*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) value.